# artisan serve command reads the filenames from public/plugins folder and display filenames on console - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, artisan-serve

[image: After running php artisan serve, this is being displayed on localhost and the same texts on console. Previously everything was working fine (since last 6+ months), this has been occurred unexpectedly.]

What has been done to fix this issue:

1. composer, npm updated. --> didn't solved
2. new wamp server installed and tried. --> didn't solved
3. php version 7.4.9, since running artisan serve command on another laravel project, it is running fine without this issue.
4. config, cache, cookies all cleared and ok.
5. Also since after this issue when click on Login, it says LoginController not found but it there where it was.
6. No major changes on the code level.

Issue occurred all of sudden on running project.

Comment: looks like you're missing an header and/or context type when writing the output... share your relevant code for better quality answers.

Comment: @weirdgyn Actually there has been no code modification either on the controller side or on the template side. So I don't exactly can't figure out what files/code to share. As told earlier, this happened all of sudden while everything was working fine. So I made above mentioned changes/updates in case something got crashed. But nothing solved the issue, even with new WAMP server.

Comment: that's a problem... SO moderation will sooner or later mark your question as non compliant with policies (since it's not talking about code) and then close it. 
If you still haven't found or focused any suspicious code you have to get deeper in your investigation . People here simply cannot/will not to access your work unless you post it here so it's quite difficult to examine a problem like this and provide an useful answer.  If you're lucky you could have to deal with many *opinions* (that by-the-way is also an unwelcome behaviour on SO).

Comment: the solution or the issue is still unknown. But it worked when I cloned the repo from git. That didn't threw any such error. But the last push to the origin was when I encountered that issue, though cloning the same repo it didn't encounter any issue.